# Grouping and adding values based on row string with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have the following pandas data set:

```
date, pair, value, fruit
2019-11-15 09:35:33,EUR,10,BANANA
2019-11-15 09:35:32,EUR,12,BANANA
2019-11-15 09:35:31,EUR,21,APPLE
2019-11-15 09:35:30,EUR,17,ORANGE
2019-11-15 09:35:28,EUR,19,BANANA
2019-11-14 09:58:05,EUR,37,APPLE
2019-11-14 09:23:42,EUR,41,ORANGE
2019-11-14 09:23:42,EUR,15,APPLE
```

How can I group and add the `value` field for the same fruit(s)?

So I get,

```
[
 ['BANANA', 'APPLE', 'ORANGE'],
 [41, 73, 58]
]
```

`41` Being the sum of all `BANANA` values,

`73` Being the sum of all `APPLE` values,

`58` Being the sum of all `ORANGE` values.

The intention is draw a bar chart.

Comment: `df.groupby('fruit').sum()`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help

```
a=your_df.groupby(["fruit"]).sum()["value"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for python3.6:

```
import pandas as pd

sum_fruit = data.groupby('fruit').sum()
print(sum_fruit)
```